# Can I hide specific network shares from sidebar in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, network-shares, shortcuts

I have a number of network drives mapped and other network locations added to Windows Explorer so I can have quick access to other network shares for backups and whatnot. I also added some FTP shortcuts for my phones so I can transfer files to and from my computer to my phone as needed. The FTP service is only run on demand when I need to transfer files so those links are dead unless I use it.

Problem is, since those links are technically dead most of the time and windows has a tendency to want to keep the sidebar updated, I frequently run into problems where I'm dragging files between explorer windows to transfer files. If I happen to hover over any of these dead links, windows explorer will freeze for about 15 or so seconds as if it's trying to update the status and this interrupts the drag-and-drop. I could get around it by avoiding it entirely or collapsing "This PC" to hide it but everything's open by default and I'm not going to do that, I still use the sidebar.

[image: links in sidebar]

Is there a way I can make it so these links are hidden so I don't run into this issue?

It's not a blocker or anything, just annoying enough that I'd want to find a solution for.

Comment: Much easier (for me in my view) to delete unused drives/folders with NET USE folder /delete  and then only keep the folders you want. Local unused folders do not slow File Explorer down.